# Simple Stack Calculator can't give proper fractional answers

Tags: java

Im trying to fix my code which is a simple calculator in Java made using stacks and a token class. I am having an error every time I have a decimal number as an answer. For example, if I input 11/2 it will give me 1. Its an odd error and I don't know how to fix it and was wondering if someone could tell me how. Thank you for any help!

```
public class SimpleCalcSkeleton {

private enum TokenType {WS,LP,RP,NUM,OP};

private static class Token {

    // instance variables
    private String value;
    private TokenType type;

    // constructor
    public Token(String v, TokenType t) {
        this.value = v;
        this.type = t;
    }

    // toString() is important for diagnostic output
    public String toString() {
        return ("[" + value + ";" + type.toString() + "]");
    }

    // getter or accessor methods for the instance vars or properties
    // setter methods are not needed
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public TokenType getType() {
        return type;
    }
}

private static TokenType getTokenType(char c) {
    TokenType type=null;

    if(c==' '){
        type=TokenType.WS;
    }

    if(c=='('){
        type=TokenType.LP;
    }

    if(c==')'){
        type=TokenType.RP;
    }

    if((c=='+')||(c=='-')||(c=='*')||(c=='/')){
        type=TokenType.OP;
    }

    if((c=='0')||(c=='1')||(c=='2')||(c=='3')||(c=='4')||(c=='5')||(c=='6')||(c=='7')||(c=='8')||(c=='9')){
        type=TokenType.NUM;
    }
    return type;  
}

private static int getAssoc(Token token) { 
    String word = token.getValue();
    int number =0;

    if((word.equals('+'))||(word.equals('-'))){
        number=1;
    }

    if((word.equals('*'))||(word.equals('/'))){
        number=2;
    }

    return number;
    }

private static ArrayList<Token> parse(String s) {
    if(s==null||s.length()==0){
        return null;
    }

    ArrayList<Token> list= new ArrayList<Token>();

    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
        char c=s.charAt(i);
        TokenType type = getTokenType(c);
        String symbol= Character.toString(c);

        if(type==null){
            System.out.print("Error: null");
        }
        else if(!type.equals(TokenType.WS)){
            list.add(new Token(symbol,type));
        }
      }
      return list;
    }

private static ArrayList<Token> infixToPostfix(ArrayList<Token> intokens) {
    Stack astack = new Stack();
    ArrayList<Token>outokens=new ArrayList<Token>();

    for(int i=0;i<intokens.size();i++){
        Token in= intokens.get(i); 

        if(in.getType()==TokenType.NUM){
            outokens.add(in);
        }
        if(in.getType()==TokenType.LP){
            astack.push(in);
        }
        if(in.getType()==TokenType.RP){
            Token top=(Token)astack.peek();

            while(top.getType()!=TokenType.LP){
                astack.pop();
                outokens.add(top);

                top=(Token)astack.peek();
                if(top.getType()==TokenType.LP){
                    astack.pop();
                    break;
                }}}

        if(in.getType()==TokenType.OP){
            if(!astack.isEmpty()){
                Token top = (Token)astack.peek();

                while((top.getType()==TokenType.OP)&&(getAssoc(top)>=getAssoc(in))){
                    astack.pop();
                    outokens.add(top);
                    if(!astack.isEmpty())
                        top=(Token)astack.peek();                      
                    else break;
                }}
        astack.push(in);
        }
    }

    while(!astack.isEmpty()){
        Token top=(Token)astack.peek();
        astack.pop();
        outokens.add(top);
        if(!astack.isEmpty())
            top=(Token)astack.peek();
        else break;
        }
      return outokens;
    }

private static Token evalOp(Token op, Token t1, Token t2) { 
    String one = t1.getValue();
    String two = t2.getValue();
    String opener = op.getValue();
    int output =0;

    int first = Integer.parseInt(one);
    int second = Integer.parseInt(two);

    if(opener.equals("+")){
    output = second+first;
    }
    if(opener.equals("-")){
    output = second-first;
    }
    if(opener.equals("*")){
    output = second*first;
    }
    if(opener.equals("/")){
    output = second/first;
    }

    String last = Integer.toString(output);
    Token total = new Token(last,TokenType.NUM);
    return total;
    }

private static String evalPostfix(ArrayList<Token> intokens) {
    Stack right = new Stack();

    for(int i=0;i<intokens.size();i++){
        Token in=intokens.get(i);

        if(in.getType()==TokenType.NUM)
            right.push(in);

        else if(in.getType()==TokenType.OP){
            Token at = (Token) right.pop();
            Token bat = (Token) right.pop();
            Token cat = evalOp(in,at,bat);
            right.push(cat);
        }
    }
    return right.toString();
}

public static String evalExpression(String s) {

    ArrayList<Token> infixtokens = parse(s);
System.out.println("\tinfix tokens: " + infixtokens);

ArrayList<Token> postfixtokens = infixToPostfix(infixtokens);
System.out.println("\tpostfix tokens: " + postfixtokens);

return evalPostfix(postfixtokens);
}

public static void commandLine() {
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

while (true){
    System.out.print("> ");
    String word = in.nextLine();

        if (word.equals("quit")) {
                break;
    }

    else {
            System.out.println(evalExpression(word));
    }
}           
}
}

class SimpleCalcTest {

public static void test() {
    String[] inputs = {
        "3*4 + 5",
        "3 + 4*5",
        "(1+1)*(5-2)",
        "(3*4+5)*(3*3 + 4*4)"
    };

    for (int i=0; i<inputs.length; i++) {
        String s = inputs[i];
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("test:  input = " + s);
        String r = SimpleCalcSkeleton.evalExpression(s);
        System.out.println("\tresult = " + r);
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    SimpleCalcSkeleton.commandLine();
            SimpleCalcTest.test();
}
}
```

Comment: Do the other operations work?

Comment: To begin with, you're doing all your arithmetic using integers so there cannot be any fractional results.  Why `11/2` equals `1` is a different question and probably has to do with how you tokenized the input.  It appears your tokens are limited to 1 character long. I don't see any logic to handle multi-digit numbers.

Comment: If you have not done so already, the first step is to run this in your IDE debugger and step through the code one line at a time.  This will let you become familiar with what is _actually_ happening and hopefully you'll see where the behavior differs from your expectations.  Be aware that questions of the form "here's my code, please tell me what's wrong" (as yours is) are generally considered off-topic here.  You are expected to make a serious effort to debug the code yourself and tell us what you have done so far.

Comment: So just by the way tokens work, my answer can only come back with single digit numbers that are 0-9?

Comment: Also other operations do work such as 3+3/2

Comment: And what is the answer for `3+3/2`?  If it is `3` then you've got your operator precedence wrong as well.

Comment: You know what Jim Garrison. You have defeated the Grand Wizod. I will leave stack overflow and never return.

PS. The answer was 3